# Where is SVN on OS X Mountain Lion?

Tags: svn, osx-mountain-lion

I upgraded to OS X Mountain Lion and found out SVN is no longer present. I use Netbeans 6.9.1 in conjunction with Apache's SVN.

How can I get it back and working?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

Install the latest Xcode from the Mac App Store.

Go to *Xcode » Preferences » Downloads » Command Line Tools » Install*.

[image]

If you don't want to download/install Xcode, you can always just download Command Line Tools for Mountain Lion from [Developer Downloads](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: For anyone else who finds it doesn't work, I had to close my terminal window and open a new one before SVN would stop complaining about bad versions after installing the CLT from inside Xcode.

Answer (score 11):

If you have Xcode installed and if you use bash :

```
$> vi ~/.profile
```

add this at the end of your .profile
PATH="${PATH}:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/"

```
$> source ~/.profile
```

It should be working

Comment: I initially +1'ed the accepted answer, but I added a +1 here because this worked without having to install anything (which may only have "installed" what was already there anyway.)

Comment: You need to have Xcode installed in order for this to work. Also if some other software doesn't use the same environment as your user it won't be able to find svn (or any other package supplied by Xcode).

Comment: yeah, but if you install xcode it's not enough -- thanks jfgrang

Answer (score 11):

Also checkout Homebrew for these type of packages :

```
brew install svn
```

Comment: Use this to get svn 1.7 on OSX Lion

Answer (score 5):

XCode will only install SVN 1.6.18 (r1303927). But you can easily install Subversion from Apache. Just download the source files at http://subversion.apache.org/download/#recommended-release, unpack and go into Terminal. Navigate to the folder you just unpacked via

```
cd /path/to/folder
```

(you can drag & drop the folder from Finder into Terminal). Then type

```
./configure
```

wait

```
make
```

wait quite some time

```
sudo make install
```

However you might need to change your PATHS by going to /etc

```
cd /etc
```

and open the PATHS-File

```
open paths
```

In my case, the old installation was in /usr/bin/svn (you can check that with "which svn"), the new one is in /usr/local/bin. Both are in the PATHS-file, but in the "wrong" order.

Comment: Nice to see the command-line 'make' answer.  However, it is worth noting that this method very well may require (unmet) pre-requisites, such as BerkeleyDB and SQlite.  Be prepared to grab other software from the internet to support this method.

Answer (score 4):

You can also install the SVN and other command line tools without installing the full xcode as per this article:

http://blog.grapii.com/2012/08/svn-missing-in-mac-os-x-10-8-mountain-lion/

Comment: Agreed. This is a better answer; download 116MB (Command Line Tools) instead of 1.5GB (XCode).

Answer (score 3):

You can install one of the binary distributions available at

[Apache Subversion Binary Packages - Mac OS X](http://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#osx)

I've chosen the WANdisco distribution myself. Keep in mind you need to stay on the same major version as Netbeans use, if you are touching your working copy from both NetBeans and the command line. So if NetBeans 6.9.1 is still using Subversion 1.6, you should go for Subversion 1.6.18, not 1.7.5. Or upgrade to a newer NetBeans version with Subversion 1.7 support.

**Update:** Looks like NetBeans svn support is interacting with the command line client, and supports svn 1.6.x and newer: [Guided Tour of Subversion - Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html). I would go for the newest 1.7.x version then.

Answer (score 1):

You can always install Subversion through [MacPorts](http://www.macports.org/install.php).

```
sudo port install subversion
```

Comment: Xcode's command-line tools are a requirement for MacPorts to work, so: no CLI tools, no subversion, whether by compiling it by hand or through MacPorts.

Comment: `Error: Port subversion not found`. I am using MacPorts 2.1.2 on Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1):

If you install through XCode you'll get svn 1.6.x. If you need 1.7.x you'll have issues with http urls of repositories so you'll need to install neon as well. This is my blog post about how to do this (the first part is why)

http://nemanjakovacevic.net/blog/2013/01/svn-android-pre-compiler-and-mac-os-x-pita-combination/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there are many problems with svn 1.7.5 on Apple's Mountain Lion. The svn version of the Apache site has a wrong Neon version (causing svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for http*).
The command line version of WANdisco has problems and is therefor not ready, while CollabNet does not have a build for OSX Mountain Lion.

The GUI version of Syncro is up-and-running for 1.7.5, command line versions are not.

The best is to stay on the 1.6 until all problems are solved.

Answer (score 0):

It may be present in `/opt/subversion/bin`. If so, you can add that directory to the `PATH` environment variable in your `~/.bash_profile file`.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo ln -s  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/svn /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 0):

SVN might **already** be installed but it may not be available in Terminal because SVN is not included in the path.

In 10.8, they moved SVN to the Application folder. You need to add this folder to the /etc/paths file so it is available in Terminal.

1. First, open nano:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/paths
   ```

   Note that this will prompt for a password. Enter the correct password.
2. In the nano editor, add the following line at the end of the file:

   ```
   /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin
   ```
3. Use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> to write the files and <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> to exit Nano Editor.
4. Quit Terminal (<kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd>) and restart. Type `SVN Help` and you will see that SVN is now available in the Terminal window.

Here's some further help: http://www.threeeyedbird.com/blog/2012/08/06/where-did-svn-go-after-upgrading-to-os-x-mountain-lion-10.8/