# Why can't I install subversion on OS X?

Tags: macos, svn

I am trying to install `svn` (from CollabNet) on OS X. I am running the package I downloaded, and then click all through the installer. But when I reach the "installation destination" it gives me a single option "install for all users", and I just can't click on it, it is grey. I can't go past that point, and choose installation directory.

This seems more like a permission problem for the installer somewhere, but no error is given, and I don't know how to fix it.

Any ideas?

EDIT: I am using OS X 10.8. I also tried running "open package-file-name" from a terminal, logged in as root, and that didn't work either.

The version I downloaded for svn was for OS X 10.7 - that's the latest I could find.

Comment: im presuming your computer is fairly new, go into System Preferences and then into Security. See if you have your application installation limited to only applications downloaded from the app store. If this isn't the case, we can run the installer from source using `sudo`

Comment: How much time did you wait with the grayed-out option? It takes some time (more than two minutes on my MacBook Pro) to finish the checks and allow to continue.

Answer (score 1):

You could install [**Xcode**](https://developer.apple.com/technologies/tools/), it includes **Subversion**.

Otherwise, there is further information available [**here**](https://superuser.com/questions/455214/where-is-svn-on-os-x-mountain-lion).

Answer (score 0):

You could try [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)

```
brew install svn
```